# Qt (QML) Dashed Circle

Tags: qt, html5-canvas, qml

Is there any way to draw half dashed circle in QML? I drawn half circle in this way

```
   var Circle = getContext("2d");
          Circle.save();
          var CircleGradient = 
 Circle.createLinearGradient(parent.width/4,parent.height,parent.width/4,0);
        CircleGradient.addColorStop(0, firstGradientPoint);
                  CircleGradient.addColorStop(1, secondGradientPoint);
                  Circle.clearRect(0, 0, parent.width, parent.height);
                  Circle.beginPath();
                  Circle.lineCap = "round";
                  Circle.lineWidth = 10;
                  Circle.strokeStyle = CircleGradient
                  Circle.arc(parent.width/2, parent.height/2, canvas.radius - (Circle.lineWidth / 2), Math.PI/2, canvas.Value);
                  Circle.stroke();
                  Circle.restore();
```

Result

[image]

But how can I make it dashed like this.

I need

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal code which can be executed and tested.

Comment: Unfortunately the QML canvas implementation doesn't have the `setLineDash()` method implemented, even though it is supposed to be HTML canvas compatible... So you either need to draw a sequence of interupted lines as the answer suggests, or you could go for a `QQuickPaintedItem` implementation that uses `QPainter` which can draw dashed lines.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is very outdated, but it might help someone. You can use [Qt Quick Shapes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html#details) (since Qt 5.10) to render what you want. It's not copy-paste code, but more of an approach:

```
Shape {
    ShapePath {
        id: shapePath
        strokeColor: "black"
        strokeStyle: ShapePath.DashLine
        dashPattern: [6, 8]
        fillColor: "transparent"

        PathArc {
            x: 0
            y: radiusX + radiusY
            radiusX: 100
            radiusY: 100
            useLargeArc: true
        }
    }
}
```

[PathArc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-patharc.html) documentation has pretty much everything you need. Here are some more [Shape Examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-shapes-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

I know QML little bit but never coded.
But you can solve your problem by logic.

Here is the logic- Code below is pseudo, will not work but will give you an idea.

**Draw the small arcs in loop with spaces in between.**

```
//DECLARE YOUR ANGLES START AND END
startAngle = 0.0;
endAngle = pi/20;// 10 ARCS AND 10 SPACES

 while (q++ < 10){

   Circle.arc(parent.width/2, parent.height/2, canvas.radius - (Circle.lineWidth / 2), startAngle, endAngle, canvas.Value)

   //LEAVE SPACE AND CREATE NEW START AND END ANGLE.
   startAngle = endAngle + endAngle;
   endAngle  = startAngle + endAngle;
 }
```