# Draw a dashed circle in QML without Canvas

Tags: qt, canvas, qml

I want to draw a dashed circle whose radius will grow or shrink depending on a variable. I've only found a `Canvas`-based solution: [Qt (QML) Dashed Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309676/qt-qml-dashed-circle)

I am a little bit surprised to not have found another solution. I'm afraid the `Canvas` solution will consume too many resources. Is there any other practical way?

Comment: I guess the right way is creating custom item derived from `QQuickItem` or `QQuickPaintedItem`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use Canvas another approach would be to use `QQuickPaintedItem` and paint a circle yourself. Implementation would look something like this:

dashcircle.h

```
#ifndef DASHCIRCLE_H
#define DASHCIRCLE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QPainter>

class DashCircle : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DashCircle(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);

    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter);
};

#endif // DASHCIRCLE_H
```

dashcircle.cpp:

```
#include "dashcircle.h"

DashCircle::DashCircle(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{

}

void DashCircle::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::DashLine));
    painter->drawEllipse(0, 0, width() - 1, height() - 1);
}
```

Register type:

```
qmlRegisterType<DashCircle>("Custom", 1, 0, "DashCircle");
```

Create in qml:

```
DashCircle {
    x: 50
    y: 50
    width: 50
    height: 50
}
```

Result:

[image: circle]

Comment: nice, And You can use [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpen.html#pen-style)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Qt Quick Shapes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html#details) as I've mentioned in [Qt (QML) Dashed Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309676/qt-qml-dashed-circle/64061928#64061928).